# Sort a list of tuples based on name

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort a list of tuples based on the last names:

```
names = [
(123, 'Active', 'Michael Wilson Blessing'),
(456, 'Active', 'Tim Weaver Beadle'),
(789, 'Active', 'Lois Alan Beadle'),
...
]
```

What I want to do is sort this list based on last name. To accomplish this, I used

```
otherlist = sorted(otherlist, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

which works for unique last names, but for duplicates such as 'Beale', it seems to not want to sort it how it should, where if there's a match on last name to utilize the first name (i.e., Michael Blessing, Lois Beadle, Time Beadle). Is there a way to configure this with just the lambda, or do I need to just create a function that accomplishes this, and what might that look like?

Comment: _"how it should, where if there's a match on last name to utilize the first name"_ - where exactly do you think this logic is currently included? `lambda x: x[2]` just sorts alphabetically on the whole name, if you want to sort on _parts_ of the name you'd have to e.g. split them out. I'd recommend looking at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html.

Comment: To solve this, you'll need to way to go from a string like `'Michael Wilson Blessing'` to a last name like `'Blessing'` (or should it be `'Wilson Blessing'`, because it's a [double-barrelled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name)?). This is basically impossible though, human names are complex, and many people don't have last names. See [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Ah, I was afraid splitting it out in the lambda might be convoluted. But something like

```
key=lambda x: x[2].split()[-1]
```

Comment: There wouldn't be any double-barelled names, just first, middle and last. And yeah, sorting through some of these names is a workout, haha.

Comment: The code you've shown _doesn't_ sort on last name! It sorts on the entire name. Your comment _would_ sort on last names assuming the last name is always the last element in the split, but see Alexander's comment for why that is not always true. Even if it were true, this still wouldn't sort on the first name in case of identical last names. For that, you actually need to include the first name in the value returned by the lambda

Comment: A lambda isn't all that different from a function when you use it this way. You can easily define a function to do the splitting and return the correct key, and that would be a lot more readable than a convoluted lambda

Comment: @ZapRowsdower How can you be sure? People's names are complex. Some have 2 middle names, some have none. You're playing a losing game, and the only way to win is not to play. If you really need a concept of a first/last name (and I repeat: you shouldn't, try to avoid it if you can, unless you have to interact with foreign APIs that force your hand), then let the user define them as separate fields. They'll split it up for you, correctly.

Comment: Since @I'mahdi is deleting their answer a bunch of times and making it impossible to comment, I'll say it here: that answer does _exactly_ what you have described.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi That's what I'm leaning towards, as the lambda needs some sort of conditional for when there are cases when the last names match. Unless there's a way to do that in a lambda?

Comment: @Alexander oh, you're preaching to the choir, haha. The apostrophes and hyphens alone are gumming up the works big time. Looking back, I should have created a list of dictionaries for each person.

Comment: The lambda _doesn't_ need any conditional. All you need to do is return a `key` containing the last _and_ first names. `sort(ed)` takes care of the comparison with other items. Selecting the first and last elements of the result of `split` is possible in a lambda, but you'd have to split two times or figure out another way to extract the first and last elements in one shot. A regular function is much more readable and doesn't perform worse.

Comment: What seems odd to me here is that almost all of the conversation is focused on some trivial detail (do we package the code into a lambda or a function), and not the actual sticking point here, that this is basically impossible from a business logic perspective.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Ah, I see, so something like
'sorted(otherlist, key=lambda x: x[2].split()[0][-1]'

Comment: @Alexander the conversation is focused on that _trivial detail_ because that's what OP is asking about. They already said _"There wouldn't be any double-barelled names, just first, middle and last"_ in their [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73640501/sort-a-list-of-tuples-based-on-name/73640736#comment130041034_73640501)

Comment: @Alexander Very true, but the fellas who cut the paychecks want a program that matches on names, without realizing that it's a nontrivial problem given the infinite combinations of characters.

Comment: Can the fellas who cut the paychecks give you the leeway to add first and last name field inputs? That would perfectly solve your problem, _correctly_.

Comment: @Alexander Ha, you would think, but I'm a data scientist, this is how they decided to store the data many moons ago. Frankly though, you're correct, and hopefully I can convince them to split the names across fields (unless I want to tread into regex).

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function and sort based on the last and first part of each name.

```
names = [
(222, 'Active', 'Asha Baron Cohen'),
(111, 'Active', 'Sasha Baron Cohen'),
(123, 'Active', 'Michael Wilson Blessing'),
(456, 'Active', 'Tim Weaver Beadle'),
(789, 'Active', 'Lois Alan Beadle')
]

def sort_name(x):
    part_name = x[2].split()
    # Below line first sort base last part of the name and then check the first part of each name (for duplicated in the last part below line check the first part of each name)
    return (part_name[-1], part_name[0])

    # You can also consider second (middle) part of name like below
    # return (part_name[-2:], part_name[0])
    # the result will change if you use above approach


names.sort(key = sort_name)

print(names)
```

Output:

```
[(789, 'Active', 'Lois Alan Beadle'),
 (222, 'Active', 'Asha Baron Cohen'),
 (111, 'Active', 'Sasha Baron Cohen'),
 (456, 'Active', 'Tim Weaver Beadle'),
 (123, 'Active', 'Michael Wilson Blessing')]
```

Comment: This would incorrectly sort "Sasha Baron Cohen" with the Cs rather than the Bs.

Comment: @Alexander, I don't think

Comment: I think you forgot to finish your comment :)

Comment: Close, I tried this approach as well, but the correct order would be 'Lois Alan Beadle', then 'Tim Weaver Beadle'. It's sorting on the last names, but when it runs into duplicate last names, I want it to then sort by first name. Maybe I should just write an actual function out?

Comment: @Alexander, I can't understand, Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes it is: People's last names are not the substring that comes after the last space. Sasha Baron Cohen's last name is "Baron Cohen", not "Cohen".

Comment: @Alexander, Oh I don't know that, because I'm not English man ;)

Comment: @Alexander, Is this right now?

Comment: @I'mahdi Hot damn, that works! Haha, thank you, I was trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. Learned something about sorting today as well!

Comment: @I'mahdi no! Alexander is telling you that names are complicated, and that there is no one-size-fits-all rule for parsing them. See [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) Given the constraints OP has mentioned, however, your original solution of populating the tuple with the `[-1]` and `[0]` elements of `.split()` was the correct answer.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, Thanks, I think the rule can be changed but the logic like this ;)

Comment: @ZapRowsdower, you're welcome,  have a good time ;)

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do something like this if you have a version of python that supports the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html):

```
sorted(names, key=lambda x: ((s:=x[2].split())[-1], s[0]))
```

This assigns `x[2].split()` to `s`, selects the `-1`th element of it, and also the `0`th element, puts them in a tuple, and returns the tuple. `sorted` takes care of the rest.

However, I highly recommend *against* doing this. A regular function like [@I'mahdi shows in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640521/843953) is much more readable, and no worse performance-wise. Here's a demonstration:

```
import timeit
import string
import random

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def randname():
    fname = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 6))
    mname = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 6))
    lname = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 6))
    return " ".join((fname, mname, lname))

def generate(m):
    active = "Active"
    return [(000, active, randname()) for _ in range(m)]

def sort_name(x):
    part_name = x[2].split()
    return (part_name[-1], part_name[0])

def func_sort(names):
    return sorted(names, key=sort_name)

def lambda_sort(names):
    return sorted(names, key=lambda x: ((s:=x[2].split())[-1], s[0]))

mvals = [10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10_000]
lsort = []
fsort = []

for m in mvals:
    names = generate(m)
    fsort.append(timeit.timeit("func_sort(names)", number=100, globals=globals()))
    lsort.append(timeit.timeit("lambda_sort(names)", number=100, globals=globals()))
    

plt.figure()
plt.plot(mvals, lsort, label="key=lambda_sort")
plt.plot(mvals, fsort, label="key=func_sort")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("len(names)")
plt.ylabel("Time for 100 calls (s)")
ax.set_xscale("log")
plt.tight_layout()
```

The resulting plot shows that the performance of `lambda_sort` is basically identical to that of `func_sort`.

[image]

Comment: This is really interesting too, as I'm familiar with the walrus operator in passing, but have never really dove into its practical applications. While I'll go with @I'mahdi to implement a solution, this gave something else to read up on as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by last name, then first name, then middle name (if present).

This requires Python 3.8 or later for the `:=` operator.

```
sorted(names, key=lambda x: [(n := x[2].split())[-1], *n[:-1]])
# [(789, 'Active', 'Lois Alan Beadle'), 
#  (456, 'Active', 'Tim Weaver Beadle'), 
#  (123, 'Active', 'Michael Wilson Blessing'), 
#  (222, 'Active', 'Asha Baron Cohen'), 
#  (111, 'Active', 'Sasha Baron Cohen'), 
#  (999, 'Active', 'Sasha Cohen Cohen')]
```

This splits the name on whitespace, storing that in `n`, and builds a list out of the last name, then any other names, in original order. These lists are compared to produce the sorted list.

I realize on refreshing the page that I've answered *very* similarly to
Pranav. However, this does factor in all other names, and doesn't repeat a name if someone mononymous like Cher is in the list.

Comment: I mentioned it in another comment, but I had very little familiarity with the walrus operator, so it's been really interesting reading up on this thing, as most of the examples I'd seen prior had been in contexts that weren't really what I'd characterize as "applicable". Thanks for chiming in with this!